# What does this mean, "The loaded project file on disk was meanwhile changed. Do you want to overwrite the changes?"

Tags: qgis-3, save

QGIS 3.10.  When I try to save the project, I get a warning dialog (dialog heading is "Open a Project") that says,

> The loaded project file on disk was meanwhile changed. Do you want to
> overwrite the changes?
>
> Last modification date on load was: Friday, September 2, 2022 8:31:56
> AM Current last modification date is: Sunday, September 11, 2022
> 5:26:43 PM

Does that mean, do I want to overwrite the edits I have made between September 2 and September 11 with the project as it existed on September 2 (meaning, lose my work)?

Or, does it mean do I want to overwrite the changes as of September 2 with the changes I have made between September 2 and September 11 (meaning, save my work)?

I searched for the warning in Google and found documentation for an earlier version of QGIS, but it is no more clear than the warning dialog.  https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html#projects

A wrong choice will mean a lot of work wasted.  FYI, I use the autosave plugin.  It sounds like with the wrong choice I could lose the autosaved work as well.

Also, I am not trying to open a project.  Just trying to save the current project when I get the warning.  Screenshot of the warning dialog below.

[image: Warning dialog screenshot]

I tried to do a Save As as a workaround.  But that resulted in the following warning,

> Unable to save auxiliary storage ('Cannot open
> C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/QGIS3.QYaEEB for input')

And after trying that, now when I try to just save, I get the second warning, not the first.

How do I get out of this situation without losing work?

Comment: The message means that somebody else (or yourself in a different session) has opened the project into a QGIS session and saved it on September 11, 2022 5:26:43 PM. Your current project has been opened earlier and the last modification then was Friday, September 2, 2022 8:31:56 AM. If you save now the project will be saved like you have it in your QGIS but the edits that were made in the other session will be overwritten. Consider what was that other project. Was it you or someone else who opened the project?

Comment: user30184, Thank you.  It would have been me.  Sounds like you mean I had two sessions open at the same time (maybe Windows crashed and left a session open (I don't remember)?).  Regardless, I lost the opportunity to save the project or perform a save as. Tried to close QGIS and it crashed. Opened it and lost my work, but at least the project is not lost, c'est la vie.